# React Component and useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React with `create-react-app` w/ React Hooks (^16.7.0-alpha)

I'm calling `useState` as such `const [Foo, setFoo] = useState( ({bar}) => <div> Hello {bar}</div> )`

I return JSX as such `<div><Foo bar='x'/></div>`

I've also tried like this `<div>{ Foo({bar: 'x'})  }</div>`

Yet React complains that Foo is an element and not a component.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Why are you putting a component *in state*?

Comment: Its like a render prop in reverse. You pass the setState function to a child which renders a panel on the parent; the parent does not set the template for what is in the panel, the child does. Also, the child can compose any number of react components to be rendered back on the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a function to `useState` react evaluates that function and sets the returned value as the initial state. and hence in your case, firstly the destructured variable `bar` will be undefined and secondly `Foo` will be returned as `<div> Hello {bar}</div>` and not the React component.

Also you shouldn't be setting component in the React state. Instead simply define them as a functional component

```
const Foo = ({bar}) => <div> Hello {bar}</div> );
```

If at all in an extreme case you want to store a component in state it would work like

```
  const [Foo, setFoo] = useState(() => ({ bar }) => (
    <div> Hello {bar}</div>
  ));
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lymlwzjl4q)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I forgot that `useState` will execute evaluate the function.